# iframe's width resized by the android webview brokes jquerymobile layout in android phone?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-webview

I'm creating a simple app with jquerymobile build with phonegap which is using iframe in the page.

Unfortunately the Android browser has a bug(?) which forces iframes to resize to the width of their contained. This causes the width of the page to grow which forces jQuery Mobile to relayout, then it looks awful.

I have tried to set width to iframe to be smaller of the container page, but the container still resize its width.

Any idea please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by sending width of the screen to my web page and then the page get the width and set to the page.

Comment: Hi - in an attempted edit, [Mahnmoud](http://stackoverflow.com/users/183982/mahmoud-m-abdel-fattah) asked if you could provide an example for your solution? (Although perhaps he should ask a new question how to do this.)